# max-width ignoring percentage value

Tags: html, css

I have got two rows: The first one has 5 buttons, the second one has one div that should be as long as the buttons.

Here is my code:

```css
BODY * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  background: red;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
}
.rightcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
.buttons > DIV {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.buttons > DIV:first-child {
  max-width: 30%;
}
.search {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
OKAY:
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="rightcontainer">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div>Buttons 1</div>
      <div>Buttons 2</div>
      <div>Buttons 3</div>
      <div>Buttons 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      Search
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Not okay: The gap between button 4 and border should be gone
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="rightcontainer">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div>Buttons 1 long long long long</div>
      <div>Buttons 2</div>
      <div>Buttons 3</div>
      <div>Buttons 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      Search
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7a50j4oa/1/

The first button should have a `max-width` depending on a percentage.

If the button is bigger (`max-width` is used) the second row width isn't reduced.

This style is the problem (if I use px values everything works fine)

```
.buttons > DIV:first-child
{
  max-width:30%;
}
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this? Would flexbox help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution

Add this to your code:

```
.rightcontainer {
  width: 45%; /* or another percentage that works for you */
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7a50j4oa/2/)

---

### Explanation

The `max-width: 30%` in your code is not working because you have not defined a width for the containing block.

Here's the code for your containing block:

```
.rightcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here's the code for your button descendant:

```
.buttons > DIV:first-child { max-width: 30%; }
```

And here's what the spec says:

> [**10.4 Minimum and maximum widths: `min-width` and
>   `max-width`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-widths)
>
> These two properties allow authors to constrain content widths to a
>   certain range.
>
> *percentage value*
>
> Specifies a percentage for determining the used value. The percentage
>   is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's
>   containing block.

That's why your `max-width` works with pixel but not percentage values.

```css
BODY * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  background: red;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
}
.rightcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: green;
  width: 45%;               /* NEW */
}
.buttons > DIV {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.buttons > DIV:first-child {
  max-width: 30%;
}
.search {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="rightcontainer">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div>Buttons 1</div>
      <div>Buttons 2</div>
      <div>Buttons 3</div>
      <div>Buttons 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search">Search</div>
  </div>
</div>
Not okay: The gap between button 4 and border should be gone
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="rightcontainer">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div>Buttons 1 long long long long</div>
      <div>Buttons 2</div>
      <div>Buttons 3</div>
      <div>Buttons 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="search">Search</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly!
I found another solution tho:
.buttons > DIV:first-child
{
  max-width:15vw;
}
--> So I still need not set a width on the container and the max-width is reduced according to the window width. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: It's all about meeting your layout requirements and testing across browsers, devices and screen sizes. If `vw` works, go ahead. Good luck!

Comment: For me the fix for this issue was to remove `min-width: max-content` from my absolutely positioned container.